# sh: vite: command not found

Tags: npm, vite

I am using Laravel 10 with Laravel UI and Laravel UI Bootstrap Auth. Until last week, I used to run the front end normally using npm run dev. But today, when I try to do it, it throws this error:

```
sh: vite: command not found
```

I tried npm install (which was already installed anyway), tried updating vite to latest. Nothing works

Whats worse, if I start a new project, it still wont work.

I tried asking GPT, but nothing worked so far.

I'm on a M1 Macbook if that relevant

Comment: Sounds like vite isn't installed somehow .. might take a look over here on how to reinstall it.  citaiton -> https://vitejs.dev/guide/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mac? Try sudo npm i -g vite.